# Using react-helmet results into 2 sets of meta tags on react CSR page

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I am using react-helmet for my react project.

Meta tags in my index.html are:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com" />
<meta name="description" content="main description">
```

In components, I am setting meta tags as:

```
const ContactUs = () => {
return (
    <div className="less-content-container justify-content-start align-items-start">
        <Helmet>
            <title>Contact Us | Example</title>
            <meta name="description" content={"contact us description"} />
            <link rel="canonical" href={"https://example.com/contact-us"} ></link>
        </Helmet>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When final contact us page render in browser, I see two set of meta tags in the rendered html in Chrome inspect. First set of meta tags are that of index.html and second set of meta tags are that declared in component.

Also, in Google Webmasters console, I see **User-declared canonical** is set to none. That means. Google crawler didn't read canonical meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

Got the exact same problem and fixed it by adding a `data-react-helmet="true"` attribute to the definition on my `index.html`. Something like this:

```html
<meta name="description" content="main description" data-react-helmet="true" />
```

React Helmet should now replace the description on `index.html` upon startup.

Comment: If I add that to my `index.html` meta tag for description, it will not show up for pages that I don't modify the description tag.